# Color with gnuplot generated TikZ file not working (other TikZ has color)

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, revtex

I have generated a `tikz` `.tex` file from `gnuplot` and I am attempting to simply `\include{mytikzfile}` in my main `.tex` file, which uses the `revtex4-1` document class. Upon compiling I get a number of errors involving color including

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color=gp lt color border'.
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color=gp lt color 0'.
```

and a few others that are all xcolor errors. The picture shows up but it is all black. I am able to have other `tikz` pictures with color and they are produced fine. Picture on top is what I would like to see (I generated this with `gnuplot`'s `set term epslatex standalone color` option). Picture on bottom is what I'm getting by including the `.tex` file generated from `gnuplot` when I use the `set term tikz` option.

[image: Desired output]

[image: Output given]

Here is a simpler `.tex` file generated from `gnuplot` which is also supposed to contain color but does not (same `xcolor` error).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 4.6p3 (Lua 5.2; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
%% Sat Jul 20 19:15:08 2013
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (12.500,8.750);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.192,0.616);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,0.616)--(11.767,0.616);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,0.616) { 0};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,2.169)--(1.192,2.169);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,2.169)--(11.767,2.169);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,2.169) { 5};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,3.722)--(1.192,3.722);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,3.722)--(11.767,3.722);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,3.722) { 10};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,5.275)--(1.192,5.275);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,5.275)--(11.767,5.275);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,5.275) { 15};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,6.828)--(1.192,6.828);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,6.828)--(11.767,6.828);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,6.828) { 20};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.192,8.381);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,8.381)--(11.767,8.381);
\node[gp node right] at (0.828,8.381) { 25};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,0.616)--(1.012,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (1.012,0.308) { 0};
\draw[gp path] (3.199,0.616)--(3.199,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (3.199,8.381)--(3.199,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (3.199,0.308) { 1};
\draw[gp path] (5.386,0.616)--(5.386,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (5.386,8.381)--(5.386,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (5.386,0.308) { 2};
\draw[gp path] (7.573,0.616)--(7.573,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (7.573,8.381)--(7.573,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (7.573,0.308) { 3};
\draw[gp path] (9.760,0.616)--(9.760,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (9.760,8.381)--(9.760,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (9.760,0.308) { 4};
\draw[gp path] (11.947,0.616)--(11.947,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (11.947,8.381)--(11.947,8.201);
\node[gp node center] at (11.947,0.308) { 5};
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(11.947,0.616)--(11.947,8.381)--cycle;
\node[gp node right] at (2.300,8.047) {Points};
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color 0}
\gpsetpointsize{4.00}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(1.012,0.616)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(3.199,0.927)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(5.386,1.858)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(7.573,3.411)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(9.760,5.586)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(11.947,8.381)}
\gppoint{gp mark 1}{(2.942,8.047)}
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\draw[gp path] (1.012,8.381)--(1.012,0.616)--(11.947,0.616)--(11.947,8.381)--cycle;
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.012cm}{0.616cm}}{\pgfpoint{11.947cm}{8.381cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
%% gnuplot variables
```

And what it produces (points should be red):
[image]

Comment: can you post a very smple tikz picture file for us? otherwise it's difficult to tell what might be the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by very simple tikz picture file? One that is different from the one I am having problems with? Because the one I am having problems with is very long (approx. 700 lines) because it's generated from gnuplot.

Comment: yes but you can also make a gnuplot file with 5 points too

Comment: Updated with simpler example

Comment: well it looks like you are missing the preamble of this plot. there must be some `\definecolor....` commands somewhere

Comment: Friend of mine just figured it out, the style file I was using (gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty) was outdated and unneeded, it was causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question has already been answered. Although I disagree since I think a answer should be generic and not make it necessary to copy a file from some other operation system a user has most likely no direct access to.

If gnuplot with lua i.e. tikz terminal is installed on a machine:

To generate the style files and wrapper for the various TeX flavors enter

```
 lua gnuplot-tikz.lua style
```

on the command line. The files generated should be

```
  t-gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex        (Context wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex          (plain TeX wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty          (LaTeX wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex   (common definitions)
```

and can be copied to the appropriate places.

Comment: The appropriate place on OS X to copy the files is `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`

Comment: And on Linux: ~/texmf

Answer (score 1):

Linux solution (with `texlive-full` installed via Synaptic package manager):

Error comes from the use of an outdated style file: `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty`
The default one which comes with TeXlive is fine, use of one found online broke the compilation

Mac solution (with MacTeX 2013 installed):

MacTeX appears to not be installed with any form of `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` I copied the files from `/usr/share/texlive/.../gnuplot` on a Linux machine with `texlive` installed as stated above, and placed those files in the directory with my main `.tex` file. This solved the problem on a Mac.