# Problem importing Octave Plot using TiKZ - pgfkeys Error on gpcolor

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, octave

I am trying to include a set of Octave generated plots in a report, however I am constantly receiving the same error from pgf about it not recognizing \gpcolor

A MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
\gpcolor{gp lt color border}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

While this doesn't do anything in particular, it still produces the same error which is:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/global gp lt color border
```

This is even happening with other documents which have worked fine previously.

I'm using Debian Jessie, with the texlive-full package installed, along with texstudio

Comment: Could the answer here help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/color-with-gnuplot-generated-tikz-file-not-working-other-tikz-has-color - perhaps your software is out of date?

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned, to install texlive-full, but it doesn't work. Also, this was working at least a month to 2 months ago.

Comment: That other example has `\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}` - does that work? I can't run this example on my Mac.

Comment: Ah, that seems to have fixed it, I'm also having problems with \gprgb and \gpfontsize, but the rgb one looks like an xcolor issue ( needs to be \gpcolor{rgb color={0,0,0}} rather than \gpcolor{\gprgb{0}{0}{0}} ), I'll look into \gp fontsize myself

Comment: Thank you for asking this question, you answered mine by using ```\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay: It appears that this is an issue with the way .tikz files are produced by gnuplot/octave.

In GNUPLOT 4.4 it uses `\gpcolor{gp lt color border}`, `\gpcolor{\gprgbr{r}{g}{b}}` and others

In GNUPLOT 4.6 is uses `\gpcolor{color= gp lt color border}`, `\gpcolor{rgb color={r,g,b}}` etc.

Essentially, I was using two different systems Ubuntu 12.04 with octave 3.6/gnuplot 4.4, and Debian Jessie with Octave 3.8/gnuplot 4.6

Thanks to bombcar for the assistance in the comments.